# Options for getting referral history from App invite?

Tags: java, android, deep-linking, referrals, google-app-invites

I tried with Application invite through mail and sms and got successfully did that. But i need to get the referral history that invited friends history that is reffered friend name and mail id. I searched and tried about through google there is only chance to get the invitation id. Is there any other options for getting referred friends history detail using google API app invite. I here by submitted the code. Please find below. Thanks.

MainActivity

---

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInvite;
import com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInviteInvitation;
import com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInviteInvitationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;

/**
 * Main Activity for sending App Invites and launchings the DeepLinkActivity when an
 * App Invite is received.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int REQUEST_INVITE = 0;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    // [START on_create]
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
// No savedInstanceState, so it is the first launch of this activity


        // Invite button click listener
        findViewById(R.id.invite_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.custom_invite_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // Create an auto-managed GoogleApiClient with acccess to App Invites.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(AppInvite.API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();

        // Check for App Invite invitations and launch deep-link activity if possible.
        // Requires that an Activity is registered in AndroidManifest.xml to handle
        // deep-link URLs.
        boolean autoLaunchDeepLink = true;
        AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, this, autoLaunchDeepLink)
                .setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<AppInviteInvitationResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(AppInviteInvitationResult result) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "getInvitation:onResult:" + result.getStatus());
                                Log.e(TAG, "Redult:---->" + result.toString());
                                // Because autoLaunchDeepLink = true we don't have to do anything
                                // here, but we could set that to false and manually choose
                                // an Activity to launch to handle the deep link here.
                            }
                        });
    }
    /* [END on_create] */

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        showMessage(getString(R.string.google_play_services_error));
    }

    /**
     * User has clicked the 'Invite' button, launch the invitation UI with the proper
     * title, message, and deep link
     */
    // [START on_invite_clicked]

    private void onInviteClicked() {
        Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invitation_title))
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.invitation_message))
                .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_deep_link)))
                .setCustomImage(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_custom_image)))
                .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.invitation_cta))
                .build();
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
    }
    // [END on_invite_clicked]

    /**
     * User has clicked the 'Custom Invite' button, launch the invitation UI but pass in
     * a custom HTML body and subject for email invites.
     */
    // [START on_custom_invite_clicked]
    private void onCustomInviteClicked() {
        // When using the setEmailHtmlContent method, you must also set a subject using the
        // setEmailSubject message and you may not use either setCustomImage or setCallToActionText
        // in conjunction with the setEmailHtmlContent method.
        //
        // The "%%APPINVITE_LINK_PLACEHOLDER%%" token is replaced by the invitation server
        // with the custom invitation deep link based on the other parameters you provide.
        Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invitation_title))
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.invitation_message))
                .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_deep_link)))
                .setEmailHtmlContent("<html><body>" +
                        "<h1>App Invites</h1>" +
                        "<a href=\"%%APPINVITE_LINK_PLACEHOLDER%%\">Install Now!</a>" +
                        "<body></html>")
                .setEmailSubject(getString(R.string.invitation_subject))
                .build();
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);

     /*   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + "9786228072"));
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", "install");*/
       // startActivity(intent);
    }
    // [END on_custom_invite_clicked]

    // [START on_activity_result]
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: requestCode=" + requestCode + ", resultCode=" + resultCode);
        Log.e("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult" + requestCode + " :  " + resultCode);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_INVITE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Check how many invitations were sent and log a message
                // The ids array contains the unique invitation ids for each invitation sent
                // (one for each contact select by the user). You can use these for analytics
                // as the ID will be consistent on the sending and receiving devices.
                String[] ids = AppInviteInvitation.getInvitationIds(resultCode, data);
                Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.sent_invitations_fmt, ids.length));
                Log.e("sent_invitations_fmt","sent_invitations_fmt"+ ids.length);
            } else {
                // Sending failed or it was canceled, show failure message to the user
                showMessage(getString(R.string.send_failed));
            }
        }
    }
    // [END on_activity_result]

    private void showMessage(String msg) {
        ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.snackbar_layout);
        Snackbar.make(container, msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.invite_button:
                onInviteClicked();
                break;
            case R.id.custom_invite_button:
                onCustomInviteClicked();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

DeeplinkActivity:

---

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInviteReferral;


/**
 * Activity for displaying information about a receive App Invite invitation.  This activity
 * displays as a Dialog over the MainActivity and does not cover the full screen.
 */


public class DeepLinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = DeepLinkActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.deep_link_activity);
        Log.e("deepclass", "deepclass: ");
        // Button click listener
        findViewById(R.id.button_ok).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // [START deep_link_on_start]
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if the intent contains an AppInvite and then process the referral information.
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (AppInviteReferral.hasReferral(intent)) {
            processReferralIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    // [END deep_link_on_start]
    // [START process_referral_intent]
    private void processReferralIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Extract referral information from the intent
        String invitationId = AppInviteReferral.getInvitationId(intent);

        String deepLink = AppInviteReferral.getDeepLink(intent);


        if (AppInviteReferral.isOpenedFromPlayStore(intent)) {
            Log.e("invite","invite");
        }else{
            Log.e("not invite","not invite");
        }

        addReferralDataToIntent(invitationId, deepLink, intent);
        // Display referral information
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        Log.d(TAG, "Found Referral: " + invitationId + ":" + deepLink);
        Log.e("deepLink", "deepLink: " + invitationId + ":" + deepLink);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.deep_link_text))
                .setText(getString(R.string.deep_link_fmt, deepLink));
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.invitation_id_text))
                .setText(getString(R.string.invitation_id_fmt, invitationId));
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }

    public static Intent addReferralDataToIntent (String invitationId, String deepLink, Intent referralIntent){

        Log.e("deepLink", "deepLink: " + deepLink);
        Log.e("invitationId", "invitationId: " + invitationId);

        return referralIntent;``

    }
    // [END process_referral_intent]

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_ok:
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I too have been searching for this functionality, but have not found a solution - it would be great to see who was invited and better yet, the status of their acceptance. Much like Dropbox, where you can see all invitations sent and whether they've joined or not.

Comment: if (AppInviteReferral.isOpenedFromPlayStore(intent)) {
            Log.e("invite","invite");
        }else{
            Log.e("not invite","not invite");
        }

From above functionality we can get whether joined or not

Answer (score 2):

You can add this information to the deep link when you build it:

```
Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder("Invitation Title")
        .setDeepLink(Uri.parse("http://sample/refmail" + mailAddr + "/refName/" + name ))
```

Your activity intent filter is registered on schema "http" and host "sample", but the deepLink you get from AppInviteReferral is the entire string, so you can parse the requested information from it.